# Routing to 404 and using middleware.basic-authentication

Tags: clojure

I've got pretty much what is in [this code](https://github.com/markgandolfo/clojure-blog), at least the important parts for this question.

When I try to access some not-existing page, I don't get 404, but firstly, I get authentication dialog and I have to write credentials, to see 404. Thats not what I expect from 404 and routing. How can I overcome this issue?

Thanks a lot and Merry Xmas to all of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your top level lets the public paths have the first chance to supply a response, and If they don't match (or otherwise choose not to respond) then the request falls through to the part that requires authentication:

```
(defroutes app-routes
  public-routes
  (wrap-basic-authentication protected-routes authenticated?)
  (route/not-found "404 Not Found"))
```

If, after authenticating, the route is not found then it returns a 404. Because there is no way to tell before authenticating if the private routes will claim the request all requests are falling into the `wrap-basic-authentication` handler. This causes the request for authentication to happen before deciding if the path is valid. It makes a lot of sense for wrap-basic-authentication not to allow an unauthenticated user to map the site by trial and error before authenticating, so it requires authentication before it will even tell you if a path exists.

In the private paths handler all the paths start with "admin" Which if it where accessible outside the protected section of the site would be a great way to know if a request like "/foo/bar/" is not private and does not exist and thus should get merit a 404 response. If you **[hoist the word "admin"](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/wiki/Nesting-routes) to the top level handler and drop the wrap-basic-authentication into the private routes** that should give you useful error messages without allowing unauthenticated people to map the private area of the site.

something like:

```
(defroutes app-routes
  public-routes
  (context "/admin/"
     (wrap-basic-authentication protected-routes authenticated?))
  (route/not-found "404 Not Found"))
```

Then remove the word "admin" from the start of each private path.